# Horizontal RecylerView is not displayed in multiple rows properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I am using **Horizontal RecyclerView** that contains items n multiple rows. I have used **FlexboxLayoutManager** to split all items in multiple rows but the view is  not created as I want. It automatically cuts number of characters of **TextView**

I want my view like below image

[image]

My Code for this :

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp4"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp4">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnProduct"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp30"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_box"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/dp5"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Denim Jeans Outfit goes"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

Code:

```
    RecommendProductAdapter recommendProductAdapter = new RecommendProductAdapter(getActivity(), recommendedProductList, SearchProductFragment.this);
                                FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(getActivity());
                                layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
                                layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
                                listRecommend.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                listRecommend.setAdapter(recommendProductAdapter);
```

I have not specified 4 columns but I am getting 4 columns every time.

Below image if I make **TextView's** width to "wrap_content".I have not specified character length also but it cuts my text to ... . I want full text.

[image]

And if I specify **TextView's** width to "176dp" then below is the output

[image]

Please help what could be done.

Comment: Use [chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the `flex-wrap` to `wrap`

> This attribute controls whether the flex container is single-line or multi-line, and the direction of the cross axis. Possible values are:

- nowrap (default)
- wrap
- wrap_reverse

Comment: but I have not used flex-wrap any where

Comment: you should use it.

Comment: not working for me. complete text not visible also columns are still 4 no ncrease or decrease

Answer (score 0):

recycler_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:background="#F6F6F6"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp" /></LinearLayout>
```

java

```
 recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);

    recyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

output:
[image]